# Using Tuckey URL Rewrite to add file extension

Tags: regex, tomcat, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using tuckey url rewrite filter, and I want to add the language extension (.cfm) to a clean url. (I know I am making the assumption that the last word in the path is always the script.)

For example, I want to add .cfm to

```
/someScript
/module/employee/anotherScript
```

and obviously not to paths that already have an extension (as defined as having a period)

```
/someScript.cfm
/module/employee/anotherScript.cfm
```

Here's the regex rule I have in mind:

```
<rule>
    <from>^((?!\.)[\w/])*$</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true" qsappend="true">$0.cfm</to>
</rule>
```

Here's the problem.  I also want to allow for an optional trailing slash so that the slash is removed and the file extension is added.

```
/someScript/
/module/employee/anotherScript/
```

How can I re-write my regex rule to ignore the optional trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^((?:(?!\.)[\w\/])*?)\/?$
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `$1.cfm`

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/6

Answer (score 0):

After playing around, this seems to work:

```
^((\/?[\w\/\-_])*\b)\/?$
Redirect to $1.cfm
```